# for of loop how to call API endpoints with delay?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

In my Next.js application I am trying to call API endpoints sequentially with `getStaticProps`, I have third party API which only allows 5 request per second, I want to execute first 5 call at the beginning, then wait to certain time and call another 4 call, I tried to implement sequential requests with `for of` loop, It doesn't seem to work, all the function calls are execute at the same time. what is proper way to solve this issue?

```js
    const asyncCalls = [
        testApi1.getInfo1(),
        testApi2.getInfo2(),
        testApi3.getInfo3(),
        testApi1.getInfo4(),
        testApi2.getInfo5(),
        testApi3.getInfo6(),
        testApi1.getInfo7(),
        testApi2.getInfo8(),
        testApi3.getInfo9(),
     ]
     
    function delayMyPromise(myPromise, myDelay) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          return resolve(myPromise)
        }, myDelay)
      })
    }
    
    
    const resolved = []

    for (const item of asyncCalls) {
      const response = await delayMyPromise(item, 1000)
      resolved.push(response)
    }

    console.log(resolved)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a batch approach using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). There is no need to send the requests sequentially.

This solution waits for all requests to return and then waits a second before sending the next requests.

```js
// list of items/ data that you might want to use to compose your request
let dataForCalls = [
    { info: 1 },
    { info: 2 },
    { info: 3 },
    { info: 4 },
    { info: 5 },
    { info: 6 },
    { info: 7 },
    { info: 8 },
    { info: 9 },
];


const waitForMs = (ms) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms));

(async () => {
    // number of concurrent requests in one batch
    const batchSize = 5;
    // request counter
    let curReq = 0;
    // as long as there are items in the list continue to form batches
    while (curReq < dataForCalls.length) {
        // a batch is either limited by the batch size or it is smaller than the batch size when there are less items required
        const end = dataForCalls.length < curReq + batchSize ? dataForCalls.length: curReq + batchSize;
        // we know the number of concurrent request so reserve memory for this
        const concurrentReq = new Array(batchSize);
        // issue one request for each item in the batch
        for (let index = curReq; index < end; index++) {
            concurrentReq.push(fetch("https://apichallenges.herokuapp.com/mirror/request" + new URLSearchParams(dataForCalls[index])))
            console.log(`sending request ${curReq}...`)
            curReq++;
        }
        // wait until all promises are done or one promise is rejected
        await Promise.all(concurrentReq);
        console.log(`requests ${curReq - batchSize}-${curReq} done.`)
        if(curReq + 1 < dataForCalls.length){
          // after requests have returned wait for one second
          console.log(`[${new Date().toISOString()}] Waiting a second before sending next requests...`)
          await waitForMs(1000);
          console.log(`[${new Date().toISOString()}] At least one second has gone.`)
        }
        
    }
})();
```

### Edit

An even nicer solution can be obtained by dropping the `if` and using the following instead:

```js
// wait at least a second or if the requests take longer than a second wait till they are done
await Promise.all([waitForMs(1000), Promise.all(concurrentReq)]);
```

```js
// list of items/ data that you might want to use to compose your request
let dataForCalls = [
    { info: 1 },
    { info: 2 },
    { info: 3 },
    { info: 4 },
    { info: 5 },
    { info: 6 },
    { info: 7 },
    { info: 8 },
    { info: 9 },
];

const waitForMs = (ms) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms));

(async () => {
    // number of concurrent requests in one batch
    const batchSize = 5;
    // request counter
    let curReq = 0;
    // as long as there are items in the list continue to form batches
    while (curReq < dataForCalls.length) {
        // a batch is either limited by the batch size or it is smaller than the batch size when there are less items required
        const end = dataForCalls.length < curReq + batchSize ? dataForCalls.length: curReq + batchSize;
        // we know the number of concurrent request so reserve memory for this
        const concurrentReq = new Array(batchSize);
        // issue one request for each item in the batch
        for (let index = curReq; index < end; index++) {
            concurrentReq.push(fetch("https://apichallenges.herokuapp.com/mirror/request" + new URLSearchParams(dataForCalls[index])))
            console.log(`sending request ${curReq}...`)
            curReq++;
        }
        console.log(`requests ${curReq - batchSize}-${curReq} done.`)
        // wait at least a second or if the requests take longer than a second wait till they are done
        await Promise.all([waitForMs(1000), Promise.all(concurrentReq)]);
    }
})();
```

If you do not want to wait till the promises finish and just send the requests every second, you only need to await the `waitForMs()` call and forget about the currently running requests. However in that case you might have more than 5 requests at any one time as requests might take longer than a second but you will be guaranteed (within the guarantees of [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)) to fire 5 requests every second. In the end you will however need to await all Promises to guarantee that every sent request has been awaited.

```js
// list of items/ data that you might want to use to compose your request
let dataForCalls = [
    { info: 1 },
    { info: 2 },
    { info: 3 },
    { info: 4 },
    { info: 5 },
    { info: 6 },
    { info: 7 },
    { info: 8 },
    { info: 9 },
];

const waitForMs = (ms) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms));

(async () => {
    // number of concurrent requests in one batch
    const batchSize = 5;
    const allRequests = []
    // request counter
    let curReq = 0;
    // as long as there are items in the list continue to form batches
    while (curReq < dataForCalls.length) {
        // a batch is either limited by the batch size or it is smaller than the batch size when there are less items required
        const end = dataForCalls.length < curReq + batchSize ? dataForCalls.length : curReq + batchSize;
        // issue one request for each item in the batch
        for (let index = curReq; index < end; index++) {
            // create an array with all requests, not just one for each batch
            allRequests.push(fetch("https://apichallenges.herokuapp.com/mirror/request" + new URLSearchParams(dataForCalls[index])))
            console.log(`sending request ${curReq}...`)
            curReq++;
        }
        console.log(`requests ${curReq - batchSize}-${curReq} done.`)
        // wait at least a second (see how setTimeout() works in linked Docs)
        await waitForMs(1000);
    }
    // await all requests, not just those of a batch
    await Promise.all(allRequests);
    console.log(`All requests are done`);
})();
```